# How to convert an NString to an NSDate and then set the date to a UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdate

I need to convert the following string into a better readable format:

`NSString *deadlineFromTable =  @"2012-11-13T22:59:00.000Z";`

I would like to convert this into an NSDate, so I can format it.

I tried the following, but I get an incompatible pointer error assigning NSString to NSDate when I try to set it to a UILabel (the last line):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:deadlineFromTable];
self.deadlineLbl.text = dateFromString;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is `deadlineFromTable` ?

Comment: it's a string from a JSON output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two dateFormatters.

One to convert from your input string to a date and then one to convert from that date into the Label format you want.

You also need to change the format of the date formatter so it matches your string...

```
NSDateFormatter *dateStringParser = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateStringParser setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.Z"];

NSDate *date = [dateStringParser dateFromString:deadlineFromTable];

NSDateFormatter *labelFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[labelFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

self.deadlineLbl.text = [labelFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

That should do it.

Comment: thanks that worked! :) I had to use [dateStringParser setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000Z"]; for the date format ".000Z" at the end there.

Comment: Are you sure it works ? This code prints out `(null)` on my side:
`NSDateFormatter *dateStringParser = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateStringParser setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateStringParser dateFromString:@"2012-11-13T22:59:00.000Z"];
NSLog(@"%@", date);`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the dateFormatter twice. Once for parsing, and once for formatting your string.
*You cannot assign a date as a label text directly.*

1. Set format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.Z` and then use
   `NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dedlineFromTable];`
2. Set format: `dd-MM-yyyy` and then use
   `NSString *text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date];`